# variable is not changing properties inside a class

Tags: javascript, class, processing, p5.js

I'm making a ball class / object that bounces around like the DVD screen thing. But when the balls hit the edge the variable that controles their X and Y speeds dont change.

I've already tried running the same IF statement outside the class whith the exact same names and everything and then it works but as soon as i do it inside the class it breaks.

```
var dvd1;
var dvd2;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  dvd1 = new dvdlogo();
  dvd2 = new dvdlogo();
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  dvd1.move(2, 3);
  dvd1.show(200, 200, 200);
  dvd2.move(3, 2);
  dvd2.show(255, 0, 0);
}

class dvdlogo {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
  }

  move(speedX, speedY) {
    this.x = this.x + speedX;
    this.y = this.y + speedY;

//speedX and Y arn't changing when the statement is true
    if (this.y >= height || this.y <= 0) {
      speedY = -speedY;
    }

    if (this.x >= width || this.x <= 0) {
      speedX = -speedX;
    }
  }

  show(r, g, b) {
    noStroke();
    fill(r, g, b);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 50, 50);
  }
}
```

this is what the balls should do: https://editor.p5js.org/wiski/sketches/06p20NSgZ
this is what they do: https://editor.p5js.org/wiski/sketches/mym6EJenN

(If you know how to fix it tell me on here if u change the code in the web editor it doesn't send the changes to me thx in advance)

Comment: Seems to be a simple scope problem. The speedX and speedY variables you pass in to your move function are ONLY changed within the function, the reference you passed in is never changed -- i guess

Answer (score 3):

`speedX` and `speedY` are no global variables, they are parameters of the function `move`. `speedY = -speedY` changes the value of the parameter, but that doesn't effect the call of the function with the constant values `dvd1.move(2, 3);`.
The value of `speedX` and `speedY` is always 2 repectively 3, because the function `move` is called with this constant values.

Add attributes `.speedX` and `.speedY` to the class `dvdlogo` and use the attributes rather than parameters:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    dvd1 = new dvdlogo(2, 3);
    dvd2 = new dvdlogo(3, 2);
}

function draw() {
    background(255);
    dvd1.move();
    dvd1.show(200, 200, 200);
    dvd2.move();
    dvd2.show(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```
class dvdlogo {
    constructor(speedX, speedY) {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;
    }

    move() {
        this.x = this.x + this.speedX;
        this.y = this.y + this.speedY;

        if (this.y >= height || this.y <= 0) {
            this.speedY = -this.speedY;
        }

        if (this.x >= width || this.x <= 0) {
            this.speedX = -this.speedX;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are so close!

You are passing the `xSpeed` and the `ySpeed` in each frame with the `.move()` function this is making your if statement redundant!

What I recommend is specifying the `xSpeed` and `ySpeed` in the constructor, this way it'll be stored in the object for you, so your if statement can alter the fields directly!

```js
    var dvd1;
    var dvd2;
    
    function setup() {
      createCanvas(400, 400);
      dvd1 = new dvdlogo(2, 3);
      dvd2 = new dvdlogo(3, 2);
    }
    
    function draw() {
      background(255);
      dvd1.move();
      dvd1.show(200, 200, 200);
      dvd2.move();
      dvd2.show(255, 0, 0);
    }
    
    class dvdlogo {
      constructor(xSpeed, ySpeed) {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.speedX = xSpeed;
        this.speedY = ySpeed;
      }
    
      move() {
        this.x = this.x + this.speedX;
        this.y = this.y + this.speedY;
        
        if (this.y >= height || this.y <= 0) {
          this.speedY = -this.speedY;
        }
    
        if (this.x >= width || this.x <= 0) {
          this.speedX = -this.speedX;
        }
      }
    
      show(r, g, b) {
        noStroke();
        fill(r, g, b);
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, 50, 50);
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: :-) exactly the same solution. But this was obvious. (+1)